# Pre-Calculus: Equation system with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> $$\left\{
> \begin{array}{c}
> \displaystyle{\frac{x}{7} - \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{5}} \\
> \displaystyle{y +\frac{2}{x} =4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right.$$
>   is given. What is the value of  $\displaystyle\frac{5x-6y+5}{x-y}$?

I can't figure out what to do. I have applied many methods, yet I have arrived at no solution. Instead of handing me solution, I would appreciate any tips on how to arrive there.

Comment: You could begin by replacing everywhere $y$ by $4-\frac{2}{x}$.

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct equations? Your solution of $2$ does not work, I think.

Comment: Check this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ntlet1jae3

Comment: yes , I checked from graphs and  also think there is a mistake in question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Once you finish, can you edit here? I'd like to get a chance to see the problem.

Comment: I think it was printing mistake or something else. The question is same excatly as I written above.

Comment: If you go on simplifying the fraction $\frac{5x-6y+5}{x-y}$  becomes $$35\pm 10 \sqrt{\frac{183}{23}}$$
May be useful to see that $\frac{5 x-6 y+5}{x-y}=\frac{x-5}{y-x}+6$

Comment: @AlperErdem 1.sırayı $7y$ ile 2.sırayı da $x$ ile çarp eşitlikler bozulmaz sonra klasik yok etme methodu;)

Answer (score 2):

A possible way:

From the first equation:

$$xy - 7 = \frac{7y}{5} \tag{1}$$

From the second equation:

$$xy + 2 = 4x \tag{2}$$

Subtracting these two equations will give us a linear relationship between $x$ and $y$.  Substitute this linear relation in $(2)$ will give you a quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: you can also compute the Solutions of the given system

Comment: I have already calculated the from computer and have found the solutions $x=\frac{73}{40}± \frac{(4209)^{1/2}}{40}$  $y=-\frac{17}{14}± \frac{(4209)^{1/2}}{14}$ . It didn't help for the given question :\

Comment: If you have found $x$ and $y$, you can substitute those values in isn't it?

Comment: A) -2  B) -1  C)  0  D)  1  $\textbf{ E)  2}$

I think, there is a easy way to find the value  instead of finding roots and putting values in  $\frac{5x-6y+5}{x-y}$ , yet I didn't find any easy way :)